# Rows not being updated in merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a merge statement to update values in an output table when when the unique identifier appears again in the staging table. But the unique value has appeared again but inserted as a new record instead of updating the existing record.

Below is the record in the staging table (I am not including other fields as these are not relevant and do not want to make the example more difficult):

```
InsertDate  App_id  DeviceName  Account Name
31/07/2019  APP-354 SCRBSCVDK002279 #avahi-autoipd
```

Below is the existing records in the output table:

```
ID  InsertDate  App_id  DeviceName  Account Name
139059  29/04/2019  APP-354 SCRBSCVDK002279 #avahi-autoipd
```

The merge is made with a column called Unique_Comborow which is a concatenation of 3 fields:

```
App_id  DeviceName  Account Name
```

I have checked the syntax and tested this successfully.

```
MERGE Output_Linux_Accounts AS O
USING (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StagingLinuxDiscoveryData] 
WHERE 1=1
AND [Rank] = 1) AS S
ON  S.Unique_Comborow = O.Unique_Comborow COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        O.DerivedAccountCategory                    = S.DerivedAccountCategory,
        --O.adm_status                              = S.adm_status,
        O.user_status                               = S.user_status,
        --O.pam_remediation                         = S.pam_remediation,
        O.[Local Mapped Account]                    = S.[Local Mapped Account],
        O.[Account Display Name]                    = S.[Account Display Name],
        O.[Account Type]                            = S.[Account Type],
        O.[Account Category]                        = S.[Account Category],
        O.[Account Group]                           = S.[Account Group],
        O.[Account Description]                     = S.[Account Description],
        O.[Compliance Status]                       = S.[Compliance Status],
        O.[Account State]                           = S.[Account State],
        O.[Password Never Expires]                  = S.[Password Never Expires],
        O.[Password Age]                            = S.[Password Age],
        O.[Password Last Set]                       = S.[Password Last Set],
        O.[Insecure Privilege Escalation]           = S.[Insecure Privilege Escalation],
        O.[Insecure Privilege Escalation Reason]    = S.[Insecure Privilege Escalation Reason],
        O.[Last Login Date]                         = S.[Last Login Date],
        O.[Account Expiration Date]                 = S.[Account Expiration Date],
        O.[OS Version]                              = S.[OS Version],
        O.Details                                   = S.Details,
        O.Notes                                     =  Concat('Updated on - ', S.InsertDate),
        O.UpdateDate                                = S.InsertDate,
        O.[LogonAge]                                = S.[LogonAge],
        O.[Number of Keys Found]                    = S.[Number of Keys Found],
        O.[Last Key Update Date]                    = S.[Last Key Update Date],
        O.[KeyAge]                                  = S.[KeyAge],
        O.[Key Length]                              = S.[Key Length],
        O.[Key Algorithm]                           = S.[Key Algorithm],
        O.[SSH Server]                              = S.[SSH Server],
        O.[Key Comment]                             = S.[Key Comment],
        O.[Command Run on Login]                    = S.[Command Run on Login],
        O.[Key Fingerprint]                         = S.[Key Fingerprint],
        O.[In_latest_Scan]                          = S.[In_latest_Scan]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN --****not including the rest of the insert statement as this is not relevant*****
    INSERT (....)
VALUES
```

Below is the expected results (I am not including other fields as these are not relevant and do not want to make the example more difficult):

```
ID  InsertDate  App_id  DeviceName  Account Name
139059  31/07/2019  APP-354 SCRBSCVDK002279 #avahi-autoipd
```

Below is the actual results where the data has been applied

```
ID  InsertDate  App_id  DeviceName  Account Name
434553  31/07/2019  APP-354 SCRBSCVDK002279 #avahi-autoipd
139059  29/04/2019  APP-354 SCRBSCVDK002279 #avahi-autoipd
```

Comment: Why `1=1` in the `WHERE` clause? [Merge has some issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: The original writer of the statement used oracle previous where 1=1 usually helps if there is an error with the code

Comment: I would question the use of SQL collation here. They are old, outdated and sometimes lead to issues which are difficult to diagnose. Try, for example, `Latin1_General_CS_AS` instead (assuming, of course, that you can).

Comment: You join on comborow and you filter the select by rank and you force a specific collation. So your sample data doesn't really help anyone understand the logic of your statement and how it evaluates against the rows in the 2 tables.

Comment: Probably your data isn't what you think it is.   Check for differences in whitespace and invisible characters.

Comment: I would really like to see the values in both tables for `Unique_Comborow` and possibly how those values are derived and what their column type is. That is the crux of the issue here if this MERGE is inserting. That entire merge statements update/insert decision teeters on those values matching exactly, and yet they aren't shared here in this question.